# Factor analysis on Likert-scale questionaires including follow-up in R

Tags: r, factor-analysis, likert

So I know how to do factor analysis on a Likert based questionaire. However, now I have a huge dataset consisting of baseline answers for a Likert based questionaire, AND follow-ups with the same questions after some periods treatment (this is a study about patient quality of life after cancer treatment). 3 months, 6 months, 12 months, 18 months and so on.

How should I perform factor analysis on this type of data set (if that can even be justified) ? Do I run the analysis for each time period and then do some kind of analysis on them afterwards, or do I run the analysis on everything at the same time (this seems illogical to me).

Comment: All that depend on your suppositions. Do you admit that factor structure in your case should change over time? Should central tendencies or variances change? It they may change, will you want to ignore or to take it into account?

Comment: It could change over time. The treatment usually either gives acute side effects (present within the first months, i.e. the questionnaires after that would be influenced) and then disappear later on, long term side effects that might not present itself before maybe some of the last questionnaires, or no side effect at all.